# Only numbers are missing Weasyprint PDF

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, weasyprint

That's it, I'm on Mac Mojave with weasyprint-44, python 3.6, and Cairo etc. versions match. The PDF renders nicely otherwise - symbols and letters are fine - just no numbers?

So weird.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've got the same problem- did you find a solution?

Comment: Happened to me today. It's funny, you immediately notice that big chunks of it are missing. Then closer it's like "it's just the numbers?" I have alpha and underscores and table borders, even the parens. Would love to turn this in to the biz. team just for their reactions (it's stat. analysis, so it's garbage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by eliminating the font `"Segoe UI Emoji"` from a font-family CSS declaration. Numbers started appearing again once this font was removed from CSS.

The bug seems to have started with some change on macOS 10.14.4.

Answer (score 4):

I am on Mac (Mojave 10.14.5) and have the same problem. I managed to fix it by defining a different font family for print. In my case, I use:

```
font-family: "Open Sans", Calibri, Candara, Arial, sans-serif;
```

everything prints out nicely.

Comment: Indeed, it was a whacky font causing the problems originating from bootstrap.

Comment: Confirming this works for me using Mac OS X Big Sur, Python 3.8.5, and Bootstrap 4.6.0

Answer (score 2):

The same issue occurs on Sierra (10.12) and High Sierra (10.13), as well as Mojave (10.14), especially when using Bootstrap 4.

The default `body` definition looks as follows:

```
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
```

Where both `Apple Color Emoji` as well as `Segoe UI Emojii` can cause the final PDF to not display numbers properly.

Removing all mentions of the `Emojii` fonts brings the numbers back.

Note: The numbers are still there, you can copy and paste them, however, they are not actually visible.

Comment: This is exactly how I ran into my solution above. I had code using Bootstrap 4 that worked on 10.14.3 but not 10.14.4.